# xajax - bad response when calling a static method

Tags: php, response, static-methods, xajax

When using XAJAX I have a call to a function that trims a string. this is a simple function and works just as expected.

Now I want to make this function available to the whole system so I have added it to a helper class as a static method. ever since I moved this function to this class I get a bad response, something like this.

```
Error: the XML response that was returned from the server is invalid.
Received:



some code here...



You have whitespace in your response.
```

This message most of the times comes up when there is a fatal error, but nothing shows up in the error log...
don't really know what to do from here, any suggestions?

I have included the file, so I know is not an include problem, the static method gets called, but the response that comes back from XAJAX is bad.

Thank you

Comment: what exacly are you "trimming"? the hole xml file or parts of it?

Comment: is just a name to display on the screen, it trims it if is longer than a user defined length. nothing to do with the actual xml

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambigious at best.  It's pretty easily described by the error your returning ... your currently return an invalid response (i.e. code/non-formatted xml documentation).

Generally, I setup a mail function in a class and include that class into my xajax responses so that I can email myself the response before objectResponse the value.

```
function xajax_loader($formdata){
global $cms,$debug;
$objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
$dataset = $cms->get_data($cms->_getpage);
$columns = $cms->get_columns($cms->_getpage);
$objResponse->loadXml(search($dataset, $formdata, $columns));
//$debug->phpmailer($dataset,$cms->_getcurrentuser());
return $objResponse;
}
```

$frw->xajax->registerFunction('xajax_loader');

Also of note: if you are using Mozilla View your Error Console and it will tell you which line you have a failure on.  IE8/9 F12 and similar results will be provided in the script debugger.